# XNA Unknown memory leak causes game crash

Tags: c#, debugging, memory-leaks, xna, game-physics

**Hello!**
I am working on a space shooter game in XNA. The game works as it should I can't find any errors in the code. However, when I fire too many bullets from my spaceship(s), the game crashes.

I do delete the bullets as they go off screen, but they're still causing a game crash.

The error message I get is:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.Drawing.dll"
>   "Additional information: The process has ended"

And the marked line is:

```
public Bullet(Texture2D texture, Color color, float speed, int scale)
```

Here is the relevant code for the bullet:

**Game1.cs**

```
   // This is a member variable at the top of my program
   public List<Bullet> bullets = new List<Bullet>();  

   // Further down
    public void UpdateBullets()
    {
        foreach (Bullet bullet in bullets)
        {
            bullet.position.Y += bullet.speed;
            if (bullet.position.Y >= GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height || bullet.position.Y + bullet.height <= 0
            || bullet.position.X < 0 || bullet.position.X - bullet.width > GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width)
                bullet.isVisible = false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (!bullets[i].isVisible)
            {
                bullets[i].texture = null;
                bullets[i] = null;
                bullets.Remove(bullets[i]);
            }
        }
    }  

    public void Shoot(Entity e, Texture2D texture)
    {
        Bullet newBullet = new Bullet(texture, e.color, e.bulletSpeed, 16);
        newBullet.owner = e;
        newBullet.SetPositionByBottom(e.bulletPoint);
        newBullet.isVisible = true;

        if (bullets.Count() < maxBullets)
        {
            bullets.Add(newBullet);
        }
    }  

        public void DrawBullets()
    {
        foreach (Bullet bullet in bullets)
        {
            bullet.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    }
```

**Bullet.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace SpaceShooter
{
    class Bullet : GameObject
    {
        public float speed;
        public bool isVisible;
        public Entity owner;

        public Bullet(Texture2D texture, Color color, float speed, int scale)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.texture = texture;
            this.speed = speed;
            width = scale;
            height = scale * 2;
            isVisible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Any ideas as of where the memory leak is coming from, or if it even is a memory leak at all?**

Comment: That doesn't sound like a memory leak to me.  Can you confirm via Task Manager? I agree with Skull's suggestion below to alter the way you remove items.  Even so, failure to do so generally leads to a different type of exception such as _"collection was changed"_

Comment: I have no idea how to check via the task mangager to be quite honest. Also, I did try the method that Skull provided to no avail.

Comment: When you run your game, take note of how much memory it is consuming in Task Manager. As a rough guide - a 32bit .NET app without doing anything "too special" memory wise will "blow up" at approximately 1.5GB RAM usage (exact details won't fit in this comment).  A more accurate way to check for leaks is via Visual Studio's **Code Analysis**

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over the list of bullets backwards:

```
for (int i = bullets.Count()-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (!bullets[i].isVisible)
    {
        bullets[i].texture = null;
        bullets[i] = null;
        bullets.Remove(bullets[i]);
    }
}
```

When you remove an item in the list at i, the item at i+1 gets pushed down to i, but you're now skipping over this item. I think this may be contributing to your memory leak. Working backwards should avoid that problem.

Comment: This sounded really logical, but sadly it didn't work. I still get the crash, and the same line gets marked.  
Any other ideas?

Comment: or even simpler way: `bullets.removeall(item => !item.visible)`

Comment: public Bullet(Texture2D texture, Color color, float speed, int scale)